# How to speed up interpreted function in Matlab-Simulink

Tags: matlab, optimization, simulink, fuzzy-logic

I have designed fuzzy logic controller by means of Matlab function. Then I called this function in Simulink by using interpreted function block. Program worked but, it took too much time (about 2 days) to obtain a result. I want to speed up my controller so how to speed up interpreted function in Simulink?

Note: I did not use fuzzy logic toolbox as I want to optimize fuzzy membership parameters.

Answer (score 1):

The Interpreted Matlab Function is significantly slower than the regular Matlab Function block, but in exchange it lets you use functions that are not codegen-compatible.  If your code *is* codegen-compatible, then just switching to the Matlab Function block is the easiest way to speed up runtime (potentially quite a lot).  In that case, changing the execution mode from Normal to Accelerator may further save a lot of runtime.

The Mathworks [Comparison of Custom Block Functionality](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/comparison-of-custom-block-functionality.html) page provides additional information on the different blocks like this, and includes some tips for improving performance of the Interpreted Matlab Function block.  One thing that it calls out is that passing large amounts of data on the input/output interface of the block may consume a large amount of memory.

Alternately, depending on what your code needs to do exactly, it might make sense to refactor the design so that the fuzzy logic portion is not called by Simulink, but rather that it *calls* Simulink using the sim() function.